# How to get data from props.children to its parent in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get data from a `props.children`[Input] to it's `parent`[Form], to build an all in one form component. I am currently stuck at getting data to Input component to Form component.

This is what i have done so far =>

edit.js =>

```
export default class Edit extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            formFields: {
                name: '',
                email: ''
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form
                id={ this.props.match.params.id }
                onReceiveFormData={ this.onFiledDataChange.bind(this) }
            >
              <Input
                label='name'
                name='name'
                value='some'
              />
              <Input
                label='email'
                name='email'
                value='email@gmail'
              />
            </Form>
        );
    }
}
```

Input.js =>

```
export default class Input extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: this.props.value
        }
    }

    static setValue(val) {
        return val ? val : ''
    }

    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            value : event.target.value
        })
        this.props.onInputChange({
            [event.target.name] : event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input
                name={ this.props.name }
                value={ Input.setValue(this.state.value) }
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Form.js =>

```
 export default class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }


    saveClick() {
       /**
        Save logic => I want to get the field data here
       **/
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
                 {
                    this.props.children
                  }
                  <Button
                      onClick={ () => this.saveClick() }
                     >Save</Button>
                 </div>
        );
    }
}
```

For example, If post -> edit page and user -> edit page =>
I would like to do setting the input value inside the Form.js, Form.js will be responsible for setting the values inside those Inputs when it is mounted and it will be responsible for sending the data to the server.

I would like to the know, the scenario I have suggest is possible or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert control (make Input a controlled component). Keeping state inside components unnecessarily is generally a bad design practice. Look at the existing `<input>` it takes a `value` and an `onChange`. Your component should do too.

```
const Input = ({
  className,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <input
    className={classNames('Input', className)}
    type="text"
    {...rest}
  />
);
```

Then the parent has the state for when the form is submitted in Edit.

```
onFormSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.name, this.state.email);
}

onChange = name => e => this.setState({ [name]: e.target.value })

// ...
<Input onChange={this.onChange('name')} value={this.state.name} />
<Input onChange={this.onChange('email')} value={this.state.email} />
```

If you want `Form` to listen in on state changes you could do this:

```
onChange = (e, originalOnChange) => {
  console.log('onChange called:', e.target.value);
  originalOnChange && originalOnChange(e);
}

// ...
const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
  React.cloneElement(child, { onChange: e => this.onChange(e, child.props.onChange) })
);
```

It's a bit unorthodox but technically achievable.

Comment: `this.onChange ` gonna be a method inside the edit.js ?

Comment: exactly, added an example

Comment: You should also use `onSubmit` event on `<form>` not a button click. Your button should have `type="submit"` but with no event on it

Comment: Okay I get it :) ,  but what i am trying to do is, put all the re-occurring logic into the Form.js. I have already made a solution with this type of approach.

Comment: For example, If post -> edit page and  user -> edit page, both has this  `onChange` method. I would like to keep it inside the Form.js.  Form.js will be responsible for setting the value inside those Input when it is mounted and it will be responsible for sending the data to the server

Comment: I get it though from personal experience I prefer to expose as much control as possible. In this case you can still do this pattern but hold the state in `Form`